# Unable to import the List module from immutable.js into Angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, immutable.js

I am trying to use the `List` module from immutable.js on a new Angular 2 project. When I do that, the browser tries to GET http://localhost:3000/immutable and fails with a 404 Not Found error.

Here is what I did:

- I cloned the Angular 2 quickstart
  repo from Github (https://github.com/angular/quickstart)
- I ran `npm install` and `npm install -D immutable`

I then modified app.module.ts as follows:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { List } from 'immutable';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor() {
    let list = List.of(1,2,3);
  }
}
```

When I `npm start` the project, I get the 404 error.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more googling, I found that the answer was pretty easy. I just needed to add a new element to the map in systemjs.config.js:

```
// other libraries
[...]
'immutable': 'node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js'
```